# Setting cookie to a domain

Tags: javascript, js-cookie

Hi I am working on React, a, using js-cookie library to manage the cookies.
Right now I am creating a cookie with:

```
Cookies.set('cookieName',value);
```

My application is running in a subdomain: `subdomain.domain.com`
I need to set this cookie to `.domain` I mean, to all the sites that are of the same domain, how do I specify that when creating the cookie?

Also, is possible to make it in a generic way? I mean, if I change the domain I do not have to change the code of the app.

Thank you

Comment: You can use universal-cookies, you don't need to set domains(it's optional).
https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/universal-cookie

Answer (score 0):

From reading their docs it seems that you just have to do

`Cookies.set('cookieName', value, { domain: '.my-domain.com'})`

Note the `.` before the subdomain which denotes to be accessible to all the sub domains.

As for your last question in regards to a more generic way, perhaps the way to go is a environment variable for example:

`Cookies.set('cookieName', value, { domain: '${process.env.SUB_DOMAIN}'})`

Hope this helps